# How to retrieve attributes in hierarchical URI?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url-rewriting, restlet

Using Restlet, how can I retrieve the attributes passed in the URL?

Example: http://localhost:8888/contacts/123

in here, I want to retrieve the 123 value.

I'm using the next set of lines code:

```
router.attach("contacts/{contact_id}", ContactResource.class);

public class ContactResource extends ServerResource
{
   @Get
   public ContactDetail retrieve()
   {
     //how to retrieve the contact_id value?
     return null;
   }  
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was a while since I last used Restlet, but if I recall correctly, this should work:

```
int contact_id = Integer.parseInt(getRequest().getAttributes().get("contact_id"));
```

edit: [documentation on routing in Restlet 2.1](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/326-restlet.html)